# Como fazer para eclipse auto-completar automaticamente o código, sem precisar apertar ctrl+space?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

```
<ui:define name="menu">
    <ui:include src="/includes/menuPrincipal.xhtml"></ui:include>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form id="frmFabListagem">
        <p:dataTable id="tblFabricantes" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado"
            value="#{MBFrabicante.itens}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Fabricante - listagem
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Código" sortBy="#{item.codigo}"
                filterBy="#{item.codigo}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.codigo}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Descrição">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Opções">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{MBFrabicante.prepararExcluir}"
                                                      oncomplete="PF('dlgFabExcluir').show();" 
                                                      update=":frmFabExcluir:pnlFabExcluir" /><!-- os ícones são do jquery ui -->
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo" actionListener="#{MBFrabicante.prepararNovo}" 
                                          oncomplete="PF('teste').show();"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="teste" resizable="false" header="Fabricante - Novo"
        modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form id="frmFabNovo">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="pnlFabNovo">
            <p:outputLabel value="Descrição: "></p:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50" value="#{MBFrabicante.fabricante.descricao}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Gravar" actionListener="#{MBFrabicante.novo}" 
                                            oncomplete="PF('teste').hide();" 
                                            update=":frmFabListagem:tblFabricantes :msgGlobal" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dlgFabNovo').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<!-- modal true - ele trava a janela de baixo
     appendTo - 
 -->
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlgFabExcluir" closable="false"
          draggable="false" resizable="false"
          modal="true" appendTo="@(body)"
          header="Fabricante - Excluir">
    <h:form id="frmFabExcluir">
        <h:panelGrid id="pnlFabExcluir" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="código: "></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{MBFrabicante.fabricante.codigo}" />

            <h:outputText value="Descriçao: "></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{MBFrabicante.fabricante.descricao}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Excluir" actionListener="#{MBFrabicante.excluir}"
                             oncomplete="PF('dlgFabExcluir').hide();" 
                             update=":frmFabListagem:tblFabricantes :msgGlobal"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dlgFabExcluir').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
<!--  -->
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlgFabEditar" closable="false" 
          draggable="false" resizable="false"
          modal="true" appendTo="@(body)"
          header="Fabricante - Editar">
          <h:form id="frmFabEditar">
            <h:panelGrid id="pnlFabEditar" columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Código: "></p:outputLabel>
                <h:outputText value="#{MBFrabicante.fabricante.codigo}"></h:outputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Descrição: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{MBFrabicante.fabricante.descricao}"
                size="30" maxlength="50" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Editar" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" />
            </h:panelGrid>  
          </h:form>
</p:dialog>

</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Auto Activation triggers for Java para "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz."

Comment: A resposta de Tiago funcionou comigo.
Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Vá em

Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist 


Em "Auto Activation" 

Edite o campo Auto Activation triggers for Java para "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz."

Assim apertando qualquer tecla ela irá abrir a janelinha de auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

Vá em window / properties / facets / inclua a faceta jsf 2.

Daí ele deve dar um erro dizendo que você tem que colocar uma lib jsf2.

Se você estiver colocando a lib aponte-a, caso esteja no server coloque a opção disable se não me engano.

Por fim der apply.

Comment: Não achei a opção facets =(

Comment: Qual o teu eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse luna SR1 x64